# Calling docstrings from module

Tags: python, docstring

I have a module and I'm trying to call the docstrings using the help function. Here is the module:

```
"""Retrieve and print words from a URL.

Usage:

    py words.py <URL>
"""
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_words(url):
    """Fetch a list of words from a URL.

    Args:
        url: The URL of a UTF-8 text docuemnt.

    Returns:
        A list of strings containing the words from the document.
    """
    with urlopen(url) as story:
        story_words = []
        for line in story:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
            for word in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)
    return story_words


def print_items(items):
    """Print items one per line.

    Args:
        url: The URL of a UTF-8 text.
    """
    for item in items:
        print(item)


def main(url):
    """Print each words form a text document from a URL.

    Args:
        url: The URL of a UTF -8 text document.
    """
    words = fetch_words(url)
    print_items(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

When I type the command help(words) I get Help on module words:

```
NAME
    words

FUNCTIONS
    fetch_words()

FILE
    c:\users\cacheson\pyfund\words.py
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the problem? I see the full help with docstrings when I copy your code, import it and call `help()`

Comment: I'm not getting the docstrings. I'm using python 3.6.4 and running it with powershell. Using notepad++ for the module.

Comment: Working fine on linux for me with `3.6.4`. Sounds like it's either an issue with Windows, Powershell, or a simple error like importing the wrong file, or not saving etc?

Comment: @cache33. It works fine for me - exactly how and where are you calling `help`?

Comment: To call it I'm entering the following:

py
import words
help(words)

On different lines

Comment: Can you confirm that the file you are editing is actually: `c:\users\cacheson\pyfund\words.py` and that this has been saved/contains your code as expected?

Comment: Yes that is the file that I am using and it has been saved and contains the code as expected

Comment: @cache33. After the `import words` line, put this: `import os; print(os.path.abspath(words.__file__))` - and also comment out the `help(words)` line. What output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call help passing a function's name as an argument, or the module's name itself:

```
>>> import words
>>> help(words)
Help on module words:

NAME
    words - Retrieve and print words from a URL.

DESCRIPTION
    Usage:

        py words.py <URL>

FUNCTIONS
    fetch_words(url)
        Fetch a list of words from a URL.

        Args:
            url: The URL of a UTF-8 text docuemnt.

        Returns:
            A list of strings containing the words from the document.

    print_items(items)
        Print items one per line.

        Args:
            url: The URL of a UTF-8 text.

FILE
    /home/mikel/Documents/stackoverflow/docstring/words.py
```

As you can see it's working fine for me, so the issue is not in your code.

Comment: OP must be doing at least that to be getting the basic `NAME`, `FUNCTIONS` etc output. The real question is why does his help output not match the actual file contents...